# The button is not calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, alert

I have a button that I want to call a function when it is clicked. Right now it is just testing. As of right now when I run it, the button does not seem clickable to begin with.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      <img src="#" alt=""/>
    </h1>

    <h3>1. Getting Store categories</h3>
    <button  onclick="getCategories()">Click here to Get Categories.</button> 
    <p></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

javascript.js:

```
function getcategories()
{
    alert("TEST");
}
```

EDDIT: stylesheet.css:

```
* {
    font-family: Ariel, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #999, 0px 2px 0px #888, 0px 3px 0px #777, 0px 4px 0px #666, 0px 5px 0px #555, 0px 6px 0px #444, 0px 7px 0px #333, 0px 8px 7px #001135;
    font: 80px 'ChunkFiveRegular';
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom:0; left: 0; right:0;
    margin: auto;
}

body  {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: `getCategories != getcategories`

Comment: You called it `getCategories()` in the HTML code but `getcategories()` in the JavaScript code.

Comment: Fixing the case did not seem to work.

Comment: @AndrewRicci [Changing the case fixes this problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/b6hgn9a4/) If you experiencing another issue, consult your console for errors or ask another question specifying the current problem.

Comment: I did consult the console, and nothing pops up when I click the button. Most likely because the button is not clickable. But ok i will ask a new question

Comment: @AndrewRicci What do you mean it's "not clickable?"

Comment: I run the program and go into console. I then click on the button but nothing happens..at all and nothing displays in the console.

Comment: @AndrewRicci Could you write a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) which reproduces it? The code that you posted works, unless there's something in your CSS which is causing the button to be blocked.

Comment: @AndrewRicci Based on your update, your `img` is taking over the entire page. Give it a width/height so it doesn't cover the whole screen and you'll be good. `img { width: 10px; height: 10px; }` (adjust for however big it's supposed to be)

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you Mike C!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your HTML you wrote

```
getCategories
```

But in your JS you wrote

```
getcategories
```

Make sure these match. In the future, open your dev tools (hit F12) and look at the console. It will show you an error saying you're calling an undefined function.

Comment: It's the case. Mike C is right.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case sensitive.  `getcategories` and `getCategories` are different functions.  Change the casing to be the same on both, and that will fix your problem.

Comment: HOW DID I MISS THAT!

Comment: Stille nothing =[, changing the case didn't work.